# how to return pair from a function?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to write a function which will return pair from function but I am getting error during compilation.

```
This is the whole file:

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std; 
typedef pair<const string, const double> pr;
typedef map<const string,pr > mpr;
mpr mymap;
pr getvalue(const string s)
{
    pr pValue;
    mpr::iterator iter = mymap.find(s);
    if(iter not_eq mymap.end())
    {
        pValue = (*iter).second;
    }
    return pValue;
}
int main( )
{
    getvalue("test");

}
```

Error Message:

In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:41,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test8.cxx:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h: In member function ‘std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>& std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>::operator=(const std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: non-static const member ‘const std::basic_string, std::allocator > std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>::first’, can't use default assignment operator
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: non-static const member ‘const double std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>::second’, can't use default assignment operator
test8.cxx: In function ‘pr getvalue(std::string)’:
test8.cxx:14: note: synthesized method ‘std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>& std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>::operator=(const std::pair, std::allocator >, const double>&)’ first required here

Please help me out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Error added

Comment: please avoid fixing your question as answers try to fix it, because you invalidate them...

Comment: The elements of `pr` are immutable, but you're trying to assign to them.

Comment: In addition to SirDarius's remarks, you update your code, but not the error.

Comment: @all my question was simple : how to return pair from a function , I was not able to figure it out that why I asked here ...But I dont know why so much negativity with this question , I did not ask for compilation , I just asked for reason of compilation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The type `pr` is defined with both members of the pair being `const`. Once declared, the variable `pValue` cannot be changed in the assignment `pValue = (*iter).second`, because all it's members are effectively const.

The code can be modified to (which should compile);

```
pr getvalue(const string s)
{
    mpr::iterator iter = mymap.find(s);
    if(iter not_eq mymap.end())
    {
        return (*iter).second;
    }
    return pr();
}
```

Comment: The code would be a lot clearer if you just used a single return: `return iter == myMap.end() ? pr() : iter->second;`  (The use of `iter->second` is also more idiomatic than `(*iter).second`.)

Comment: And of course, you would normally pass the argument as a reference to const.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree. I think there are a few issues with the code, the question was originally around compilation errors, includes, etc. I just focused on the `const` here.